# How to write the simplest jQuery to fetch data from Wikipedia API?

Tags: jquery, json, api

Helllo. I tried to use the simplest jQuery to fetch data from Wikipedia API, but so far, I only got to this point below. How can I make this work? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Conchita_Wurst&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json', function(data)
    {
      $('#demo').text(data.query.normalized[0].to);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `&callback=?` to your url:

```
$.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Conchita_Wurst&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&callback=?', function(data)
{
  $('#demo').text(data.query.normalized[0].to);
});
```

Comment: Yes. Just a bit short. Thanks!